# assign HttpPost async to view ASP .NET Core6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

pls help me to get it solved. I am making a ASP .NET Core 6 MVC Application where I have to make two screens login and after validate login show profile details via WEB API call. login is successful after that I am trying to use HTTPPOST to show details into view named home/Account . here is my code in home controller :-

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Account(ReceivedToken token)
        {

            var companyForCreation = new ReceivedToken
            {
                email = "myemailid"
            };
            GetCompanyDetailsViewModel details = new GetCompanyDetailsViewModel();
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(companyForCreation), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("webAPIURL", content))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetCompanyDetailsViewModel>(apiResponse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //ViewBag.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                        TempData["msg"] = response.StatusCode;
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(details);

        }
```

how can i Assign this HTTPPOST method directly to my view

```
@model GetCompanyDetailsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Account Page";
}
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        header{display:none;}

        body {
            background-color: darkseagreen;
        }
        </style>
   
    </head>
</html>
@if (Model != null)
{
   
    <h2>Welcome to the web Application</h2>

    @Model.bankAccount

    @Model.bankName

    @Model.email

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view does not belong to your `POST` method. It belongs to `GET` method called `Account()`. So after your POST method finishes its work send data to GET method with RedirectToAction(nameOf(Account))

Comment: this way  `public RedirectToActionResult Account()
        {
            return View();
        } `

Comment: IActionResult also returns RedirectToAction. You don't have to make the return type of method RedirectToActionResult.